# Using akka actor model and kotlin coroutines together

Tags: kotlin, akka, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines

We are going do develop a project using Kotlin. Because of very high loads we decided to use kotlin-coroutines. Can the following technologies be employed together?

- kotlin-coroutines
- akka (esp. akka persistence)
- kotlin flow (for being reactive)

Comment: While this question will very likely be closed like the first one, since it's purely opinion-based, the big question here is: Why do you think you need to combine these two? What are you missing in either one so that it isn't enough for you?

Comment: I am new to akka. I want it to simplify concurrency problems. I want kotlin-coroutines because of huge online users which cannot be handled by simple thread-pools (both because of memory limitations and avoiding context-switch). And also I don't know the exact relation between "reactiveness" and "coroutines" :)

Comment: Never worked with Kotlin couroutines, but Akka is supposed to be able to handle all of that. Kotlin flow is - afaik - an implementation of the Reactive Stream specification, as is Akka Streams. Since you seem to be new to both technologies, I suggest choosing one and go with it instead of trying to mix two systems you don't really understand. What you choose is based on what you know better.